# Windows Phone 8: WCF call never finishes nor times out

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a WCF service hosted on the Internet.  I can call the service just fine using a Windows Store app, so I know it's working.  I'm trying to call the same service via Windows Phone 8.  I've created the service reference and am calling it with the following code:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TP.Stamping.WCF.WP.Client;
using TP.Stamping.WCF.WP.Client.TPStampingClient;

namespace TP.Stamping.WCF.Client
{
    public static class StampingServiceFacade
    {
        public static RegistrationResult RegisterUser(
            string userName, string password,
            string email, string phoneNumber,
            string address1, string address2,
            string city, string province,
            string country, string postal)
        {
            return
                RegisterUserAsync(userName, password, email, phoneNumber, address1, address2, city, province, country,
                    postal).Result;
        }

        public static async Task<RegistrationResult> RegisterUserAsync(
            string userName, string password,
            string email, string phoneNumber,
            string address1, string address2,
            string city, string province,
            string country, string postal)
        {
            var endpointAddress =
                new EndpointAddress(
                    "http://ourserver/TP.Stamping.WCF.Registration.StampingRegistrationService.svc");

            var client = new StampingRegistrationServiceClient("HttpEndpoint", endpointAddress);
            var waiter = new RegistrationWait(client);

            client.RegisterNewUserAsync(userName, ComputeMD5(password), email, phoneNumber, address1, address2,
                city, province, country, postal);

            var results = await waiter.WaitTask();

            return results;
        }

        private static string ComputeMD5(string str)
        {
            return MD5CryptoServiceProvider.GetMd5String(str);
        }

        private class RegistrationWait
        {
            private RegistrationResult _result;

            public RegistrationWait(StampingRegistrationServiceClient client)
            {
                client.RegisterNewUserCompleted += ClientOnRegisterNewUserCompleted;
            }

            private void ClientOnRegisterNewUserCompleted(object sender, RegisterNewUserCompletedEventArgs registerNewUserCompletedEventArgs)
            {
                _result = registerNewUserCompletedEventArgs.Result;
            }

            public Task<RegistrationResult> WaitTask()
            {
                while(_result == RegistrationResult.Error) Thread.Sleep(50);
                return new Task<RegistrationResult>(() => _result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call the service from the phone, it never completes.  Setting a breakpoint on `ClientOnRegisterNewUserCompleted` never gets called.  I've been at this for hours, help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem somewhat.  The http connection is never making it to the webserver hosting the service.  Using WireShark I can see the connections being made from the Windows 8 app, but they never show up from the Windows Phone 8 app.  What is weird is that the phone app never reports any kind of error, it's just hung until the process is killed.

Comment: OK, I've figured out what's wrong.  The WaitTask method runs on the same thread as the Completed event and thus the Thread.Sleep() is blocking that thread, so the call is never making it out.  I guess I'll have to suck it up and deal with this asynchronously.  Please close this question.